# Ghostview multiple eps file view

Tags: view, ghostscript, eps

I have a couple of .eps files in a folder, and I would like to view them one by one.
Is there any possibility to walk through these pictures like we do with Windows Image Viewer, instead of opening them one by one?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly with Ghostscript, no. You can supply multiple files on the command line and then progress through them linearly, you cannot go backwards. You could write a trivial application to do it using GS. You might try GSview and see if it does something like what you want.